# How do i make a number in An array increase by 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this question :

> An Array nums is given. Per one operation you remove one number with a
> value of K or under K from the array. After each removal K is
> increased by one.

So I have this as answer

```
function getNumber(nums,k){
  k = nums.slice(1);
  let j = k++;
  a = nums.push(j)
  return a;
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4];
let k = 1;
console.log(getNumber(arr,k));
```

It does not work as expected , its supposed to remove the first number or any number in the array and add 1 , how can I do this ?

Comment: [`slice`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns an array. What do you expect to happen when incrementing an array? Are you aware of the difference between pre-increment and post-increment? Have you tried using `console.log` for intermediate values to figure out what they are?

Comment: its supposed to remove one number in the array and increase it by one, @SebastianSimon

Comment: What you want from getNumber Function? A new array with pushed element OR just a number. And if a number then, what should be that number?

Comment: When you say, "with a value of K or under K", it is unclear what you're hoping to remove from the array. Can you please make that more clear?

Comment: Can you please post your expected output, and perhaps a second test case?